# Do closed, linear spaces always contain non-empty open sets?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For regular spaces (such as Banach spaces) we know that non-empty, open sets contain closed subsets.
The reverse shouldn't always be true (e.g. if we take singletons). Now, I have a non-trivial, closed, linear subspace $M$ of a Banach space $X$ and would like to find an open subset (not even subspace) of $M$. Is this possible in general?

Alternatively, I would like to show that given a dense subset $S$ of $X$, $M\cap S$ is never empty.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In general it's not possible. Any euclidean finite dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard norm will do the job, because a closed non-trivial linear subspace cannot contain any open ball (because the measure of a ball is positive and the measure of a non trivial subspace is $0$).

Comment: No proper subspace of any normed linear space can contain a non-empty open set and the proof is quite elementary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't even do it with the simplest examples. Try $M=\Bbb R$ and $X=\Bbb R^2$. In fact you cannot do it at all, unless $M$ is equal to the whole space $X$. Why?

Well, if $M$ is a proper subspace then there is at least one basis vector $v$ not contained in $M$. If you pick some starting $x\in M$ and try to fit an open ball inside, say of radius $\delta$, then $x+v\cdot\delta/2$ cannot be in $M$ (otherwise, subtracting $x$, you'd find $v\in M$ which is false). But $x+v\delta/2$ is in this open ball - so you cannot achieve what you want.

This observation is conceptually related (for me) to the open mapping theorem. It's often stated as (under suitable conditions) a surjective operator is open, but in fact any open operator is necessarily also surjective for this very reason. In fact we could restrict ourselves to saying, if the image of the operator has nonempty interior, then the operator is surjective.

Comment: No proper subspace of any normed linear space can contain a non-empty open set and the proof is quite elementary. I think you are making a mountain out of a mole hill.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes. Interesting how (a) I said that and (b) gave an elementary proof

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to both your questions is no if $M$ has positive codimension.

Simply take $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $M=\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$. This is closed but does not contain an open set of $X$. Likewise, you can take $S=\mathbb{Q}^2\setminus (\mathbb{Q}\times \{0\})= \mathbb{Q}^2\setminus M$ is dense but does not intersect $M$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't quite understand what you mean by $\mathbb{Q}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}\times\{0\}$ though. Does $\setminus$ mean \setminus or something like the quotient space? In either case, I don't see how $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Gollol I edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: I've seen your edits but I still don't see how $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the first "component" of $S$ is "empty". Isn't $S$ just $\emptyset\times (\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\})$ ?

Comment: Ohhh nevermind, I see it now. Thank you.